# Scroll bar css issue in Edge browser

Tags: css, vuetify.js, microsoft-edge

I am using vuetify and the scroll bar looks all good on **Chrome**, **Safari** and **Firefox**.

[image]

**The same scrollbar on **Microsoft Edge** looks like:**

[image]

Comment: It is better to open this as an issue on Github

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? From the picture, it seems that you are using the legacy version of Microsoft Edge. Besides, can you post enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is easier for us to help you solve the problem. Besides, I suggest you could refer to [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/u94ns8jc/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=u94ns8jc), it works well on Microsoft Edge  44.18362.449.0.